# How do I filter one column and get in return all variables from other column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm having trouble with the filtering function in Power BI. The situation is that I have one table, I now want to filter for one column and get in return all values that fit that filter for another column.
For example:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000448 | String | Batch 2 |
| 1 | 1000449 | String | Batch 1 |
| 2 | 1000450 | String | Batch 3 |

Now I want to put a slicer where I can insert an input of for example 1000448 for Column B. But now I want to get in return an "overview" over all the values that pertain to value 1 in Column A.

I'm a Newbie with Power BI, so maybe the solution to this issue is quite easy.